# Embedding a website into another

Tags: java, html, embedding

The first part of the requirement is to be able to embed our website (say *www.mysite.com*) into our partners' websites (say *www.partner1.com*).

Second part is the customer visiting our pages from the partners' website should be able to bookmark our pages (Bookmarked link *www.partner1.com/page/sample.jsp* should take the user to *www.mysite.com/page/sample.jsp* internally). Customer should see *www.partner1.com/page/sample.jsp* in the address bar and should not know that the page is being served by *www.mysite.com*.

Hence iFrame is out of question. Is there any better way of doing so? Is there a product that supports this kind of embedding?

We eventually want to embed our site with multiple partners and provide the same bookmarking feature.

Comment: If the customer must not know that a request is being made to `www.mysite.com` then the content will need to be fetched from the server-side of the partner's website and served as part of their response.  Any client-side embedding is going to involve making a request to your site.

Comment: When I say customer should not know that the page is being served by www.mysite.com, I meant the user should remain in the partner's website and should not be redirected to my website altogether.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a reverse proxy. This is a web server component running on your partner's site, that fetches pages from your server and delivers them to the end customer. Apache defines a reverse proxy as:

> A reverse proxy (or gateway), by contrast, appears to the client just like an ordinary web server. No special configuration on the client is necessary. The client makes ordinary requests for content in the name-space of the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy then decides where to send those requests, and returns the content as if it was itself the origin.

This in turn is more of a system administration question than a programming question. I don't know what web server your partner is using, but the [relevant Apache documentation is here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). If you want secrecy, check the web server headers carefully to ensure information doesn't leak out.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. I will run your solution by our middle-ware team and get feedback from them. Will keep you posted.